# kill a screen (but not all screens)

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, kill

I have multiple screens running on an Ubuntu server that are initiated as:

```
screen -dmS screen1 cmd
screen -dmS screen2 cmd
etc...
```

And I need to kill one screen, but not all of them.  What is the correct command to kill a single particular screen with its name?  I've read through the [man pages](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screen/) but I can't seem to find the command I am looking for.

Also I want to write this command into a bash script so I can't simply **`screen -r screen1`** then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> as I normally would.

Comment: Sorry, thought this was about Donkey Kong for a second

Comment: I love this t-shirt http://www.ohgizmo.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/donkeykong_killscreen.jpg

Comment: That is a nice tee, most people won't get it thou, unless they've seen "The King of Kong": http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0923752/

Comment: The correct word for an object of a phrase is "thee".

Comment: @Dennis Williamson, huh?

Comment: You said "get it thou" here and "Thanks thou" below. It should be "get it [for] thee" and "Thanks [be to] thee".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the man page :

```
   -X   Send the specified command to a running screen  session.  You  can
        use  the  -d or -r option to tell screen to look only for attached
        or detached screen sessions. Note that this command  doesn't  work
        if the session is password protected.
```

You can do :

```
        screen -X -S <sessionid> kill
```

Comment: PERFECT!!!
Thanks defraagh, musta missed that in the man.

Comment: Good to know :-)

Answer (score 10):

If you do a `screen -list`, you'll notice that each screen name begins with a number, which is the PID of the screen:

```
 $ screen -list
There are screens on:
        12281.pts-1.jonah       (12/21/2009 07:53:19 PM)        (Attached)
        10455.pts-1.jonah       (12/19/2009 10:55:25 AM)        (Detached)
2 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-raphink.
```

From there, just send a KILL signal to this specific PID:

```
$ kill 12281
```

and it will kill the specific screen.

Comment: this won't work because I am running it from a bash script, and I rather not have to pull the PID from screen -list that matches the correct screen... defraagh's answer above worked like a charm. Thanks thou.

Comment: Ok, good that defraagh had a perfect solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have several screens with the same name, you can kill them at once:

```
screen -ls  | egrep "^\s*[0-9]+.ScreenName" | awk -F "." '{print $1}' | xargs kill
```

- Command `screen -ls` prints screens with their process number. For example, **4773.test** is a screen with process number **4773** and the name **test**. Sample output:

  ```
  6322.ss      (05/23/2018 10:39:08 AM)        (Detached)
  6305.sc  (05/23/2018 10:38:40 AM)        (Detached)
  6265.ScreenName       (05/23/2018 10:37:59 AM)        (Detached)
  6249.ScreenName  (05/23/2018 10:37:50 AM)        (Detached)
  6236.scc        (05/23/2018 10:37:42 AM)        (Detached)
  ```
- Command `egrep` filters above sample text sent via piped line **|**.
- Command `awk -F "." '{print $1}'` extracts first column of each line. Delimiter between columns is defined as **dot (.)** by option **-F**
- Finally command `xargs kill` will kill all process whose numbers sent via  pipe |. `xargs` is used when we want to execute a command on each of inputs.

Answer (score 1):

defraagh's solution doesn't work for me, however I can kill the screen session using Raphink's idea:

screen -list get the process ID

kill -9 PROCESSID

screen -wipe SESSIONID

Answer (score 1):

Ive been dealing with this as follows:

```
process=$(screen -ls | grep screen1)
kill $(echo $process | cut -f1 -d'.')
exit
```

The explanation is that you take the output of `screen -ls` and find the particular screen you are interested in by using grep then assign that string to the variable `process`.

Since the output from `screen -ls` is always the PID followed by a period you can then use cut to get rid of the period and everything after it. in the above example we put that in parentheses and feed it to the kill command though you could do it linearly which might include writing to a temp file and reading out of that.

You need to make sure that your screen name is unique and that grep is ONLY returning the name of the screen you want to kill.

Answer (score 0):

You open a new window with

```
Ctrl A + C
```

You close a window with

```
Ctrl + D
```

or exit command within the window